# Connection between arachnid and arachidonic?

Tags: etymology

Is there an etymological connection between words like "arachnid" (related to spiders) and words like "arachidonic" (related to peanuts)?

Comment: You can find your answer at http://www.memidex.com/arachidonic-acid (for arachidonic) and http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=arachnid (for arachnid).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I think there is none. ***Arachnid*** comes from Greek *arakhne* "spider; spider's web," which probably is cognate with Latin *aranea* "spider, spider's web" ([Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=arachnid&searchmode=none)), while ***arachidonic*** is connected to *arachis* – from New Latin: genus that includes the peanut, from Greek: *arakis*, diminutive of *arakos*, a legume ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arachis%20oil)).

Comment: Yes, I was just looking up both words in Chantraine (1977), and it says the origins of both words (arachnê and arachidnê/arakos) are unknown, and no connection whatsoever is mentioned.

Comment: Does it specifically address this question or is there just no connection mentioned?